# in my web page password contain "&" symbol break the password

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created a web page and it require a password for login ,i changed my password which contain "&" symbol.all part of the password entries comes after "&" symbol is skipped.

> eg: my password is "admin123".After that i changed password as "admin&123".but web page taken password only as "admin" ,it skips all entries after "&" symbol

can anyone solve this issues

Comment: First of all, never save your password as plain text and second show you code

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Its seems like you are using get method with query string to save your password. And in query string everything after `&` will be considered as new parameter.

Comment: And your form method is `get`?

Comment: yes i use get method